# Select query for fetching data on the interval of 4 hours

Tags: postgresql, date, time, count, intervals

I am using postgres 8.1 database and I want to write a query which select data on the interval of 4 hours.

So as image show subscriber_id with date, this how currently data available in the database and

[image]

I want data like

```
No. of Subscriber |  Interval
      0               0-4
      0               4-8
      7               8-12
      1               12-16
      0               16-20
      0               20-24
```

basically in each day we have 24 hours, if I divide 24/4=6 means I have total 6 intervals for each day

```
0-4
4-8
8-12
12-16
16-20
20-24
```

So I need count of subscribers within these intervals. Is there any data function in postgres which solve my problem or how can I write a query for this problem ?

NOTE : Please write your solution according to postgres 8.1 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generate_series()` to generate periods and left join `date_time` with appropriate periods, e.g.:

```
with my_table(date_time) as (
values
('2016-10-24 11:10:00'::timestamp),
('2016-10-24 11:20:00'),
('2016-10-24 15:10:00'),
('2016-10-24 21:10:00')
)

select 
    format('%s-%s', p, p+4) as "interval", 
    sum((date_time notnull)::int) as "no of subscriber"
from generate_series(0, 20, 4) p
left join my_table
on extract(hour from date_time) between p and p+ 4
group by p
order by p;

 interval | no of subscriber 
----------+------------------
 0-4      |                0
 4-8      |                0
 8-12     |                2
 12-16    |                1
 16-20    |                0
 20-24    |                1
(6 rows)
```

---

I wouldn't suppose that there is a live guy who remembers version 8.1. You can try:

```
create table periods(p integer);
insert into periods values (0),(4),(8),(12),(16),(20);

select 
    p as "from", p+4 as "to", 
    sum((date_time notnull)::int) as "no of subscriber"
from periods
left join my_table
on extract(hour from date_time) between p and p+ 4
group by p
order by p;

 from | to | no of subscriber 
------+----+------------------
    0 |  4 |                0
    4 |  8 |                0
    8 | 12 |                2
   12 | 16 |                1
   16 | 20 |                0
   20 | 24 |                1
(6 rows)
```

Comment: generate_series is not available in postgres 8.1 version

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can do this by generating all the intervals for your time periods.  This is a little tricky, because you have to pick out the dates in your data.  However, `generate_series()` is really helpful.

The rest is just a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select dt.dt, count(t.t)
from (select generate_series(min(d.dte), max(d.dte) + interval '23 hour', interval '4 hour') as dt
      from (select distinct date_trunc('day', t.t)::date as dte from t) d 
     ) dt left join
     t
    on t.t >= dt.dt and t.t < dt.dt + interval '4 hour'
group by dt.dt
order by dt.dt;
```

Note that this keeps the period as the date/time of the beginning of the period.  You can readily convert this to a date and an interval number, if that is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for answer, query is little bit of confusing, can you please edit it and use table name as opens and column name subscriberid

Comment: @KushalJain: Gordon probably would have done that if you had posted the sample data as **text** that can be copied, not as a [screen shot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Comment: Yes, but can someone do it. Its really not understand to me, which is variable and which is columns

Comment: I think generate_series function available in some greater version of postgres. I am using 8.1 version

Comment: @KushalJain . . . Postgres 8.1 was released 12 years ago.  You might want to think about upgrading.

Comment: Yes, but its not in my hands to upgrade, I just need to work with this version only. Thanks for answers but not helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

The Previous Solution is also working...

Adding one more option,
Instead of creating a table for periods we can also use array and unnest function of arrays in this query

My code is

```
select 
p as "from", p+4 as "to", 
sum((date_time not null)::int) as "no of subscriber"
from unnest(ARRAY[0,4,8,12,16,20]) as p
left join my_table
on extract(hour from date_time) between p and p+ 4
group by p
order by p;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think if you run six different queries since you know the time intervals (lower and upper limit) will be better.